# RabbitMQ and guaranteed, timed delivery

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

Can RabbitMQ guarantee delivery of a message within a specified time interval? In other words, I want to ensure that my messages take no longer than x seconds (where x is a reasonable number) from the publish time to arrive.

Comment: Did you see https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html? A question for you: what's up if the message takes x+ 1 seconds?

Comment: Arrive to the queue or to the consumer/subscriber?

Comment: @Gas I guess the message can be dropped then. user1431072, I guess we just want to ensure the message makes it over the network in the given time interval, so at the queue should be sufficient

Comment: RabbitMQ can guarantee to not deliver old messages, ie, messages who's TTL expired